# I can't install the Software Center

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I can't install the Software Center:

```
billy2xs@billy2xs-W150ER:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and got

```
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.98.9.5).
```

so I'm lost.

Comment: anything in [this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-software-center-not-working-fixes/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=11082021) which addresses your issue?

Comment: none of those commands helped.sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade  nope
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
nope
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -f

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by Software-center, you mean the gnome-software-center. You can install it via this command:-

`sudo apt-get install gnome-software`

Comment: ok sudo apt-get install gnome-software worked, thanks!   I tried CTRL-K  for this command, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ref. @frankbell : "If Synaptic is not installed, I'd install it. It's superior to the "software centers" that seem to be all the rage today."

Comment: Well @KnudLarsen if Synaptic Package Manager is what you are ref, then I'd say it's over my head, because, say I want to remove Spotify, I don't really see it there.